# How to pass props into a component using dynamic routing with react-router-dom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

So I'm creating this small E-commerce site and am using dynamic routing every time someone clicks on a product on the home page. Depending on the product the user selected, the dynamic route should lead to a component that includes unique properties such as the name, price, images, etc., which are all retrieved from MongoDB. The issue is that I can't seem to find a way to have the data from the location where each item's metadata is fetched from Mongo, all the way down to the actual component, since I never explicitly call the component, I just have a Route component linking to that Item component.

#### App.js File

```
    <Router>
        <Header />
        <Switch>
            <Route path='/' exact component={Products} />
            <Route path='/contact' component={Contact}/>
            <Route path='/cart' component={Cart}/>
            <Route path="/item/:id" component={Item}/> {/*  <-- THIS LINE HERE */}
        </Switch>
        <Footer date={currentYear} />
    </Router>
```

#### Main Page where all Product components are displayed

Also location where data from MongoDB is being fetched and passed onto the Props of 'Product'

```
<Grid container direction="row" >
    {products.filter(product => product.product_number === "000" || product.product_number === "001")
        .map(product => 
            <Product 
                img={product.web_link}
                gridSize={6}
                linkTitle={product.link_title}
                productPrice={product.price}
                productName={product.product_name}
             />
          )
      }
</Grid>
```

#### This is the individual Product component

Ideally, we should pass the props into the item component here, but we only have a link to it

```
function Product(props){
    return (
        <Grid item xs={props.gridSize} sm={props.gridSize} md={props.gridSize} lg={props.gridSize} xl={props.gridSize}>
            <Link to={"../item/" + props.linkTitle}><img src={props.img} className="shirt-img" alt="shirt"/></Link>
        </Grid>
    )
}
```

The link to the individual item page works and all, but I can't seem to find a way to pass the data (or prop drill) onto it. Am I missing something trivial or is there a specific way to go about this situation? Will provide more information if needed. Thanks!

Comment: All you want is the details of a product in a page, right? Why don't you just create a GET endpoint `api/item/id` which retrieves that? This way, you can do a http call every time the page is rendered...something like `fetch(`/api/item/${match.params.id}`)`

Comment: That sounds like a good idea, and a lot easier. Thank you. I was just wondering if maybe there was a way I can pass the data from the initial fetch.